# mysql is inserting doublepost

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, double

I have a problem with mysql inserting. When the button is clicked, mysql insert is making a doublepost. I can't find the problem.  Why is it doubleposting?

code here http://pastebin.com/z1xx3fjt

And `postNewTopic.php`:

```
<?
session_start();
mysql_connect('.com', 'user', 'pw');
mysql_select_db('db');

function msg($status,$txt){
    return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
}

if(empty($_POST['t']) or empty($_POST['ttitle'])){
    die(msg(0,"Complete all fields!"));
}



$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ttitle']);
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tdesc']);
$msg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['t']);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO f_topics(`title`, `text`, `desc`) 
                        VALUES('$title', '$msg', '$desc')");

echo msg(1,mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Maybe this script is ran twice?

Comment: Do you have html form and insert db code in same page ? paste your html form code as well

Comment: I'd recommend using `mysqli` or `PDO` rather than `mysql` functions.

Comment: Seems like an AJAX call. Try to unbind the submit event just before binding it jQuery example $("form").unbind('submit').on('submit', function(){}); I sometimes get this sort of weird behavior.

Comment: Although it's encouraging you're escaping the values put into your SQL statement, this would be *far* easier if you were using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or `mysqli` which support [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You really should not be using `mysql_query` in new applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your **/favicon.ico** is loading and causing your script to run twice.

This happens when you have rewrite rules that catch missing files and you have no `/favicon.ico`. *First time it happened to me, it was fun!*

**EDIT**:

**Consider using HTTPfox** or some other tool that tracks browser `requests/responses` and see how many times the page is loaded. That's the first thing you need to look for.

Comment: Surely a missing `favicon.ico` won't repost a form?

Comment: If the `favicon.ico` value is empty, IE (<8 ?) will request the current page. I imagine it's rubbish enough to post it twice in that instance.

Comment: TRUE. Didn't pay attention to POST. I saw double mysql_inserts and this is the first thing that came to mind. Nevertheless, you page is triggered twice. You code should not double insert. I'll remove the answer if it gets downvoted. Otherwise, some might find comfort in it... :)